# Complicated MysQL query to find each time a user appears more than once on the same day

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am trying to query a table. There are 3 important fields: attendant_id, client_id, and date.

Each time an attendant works with a client, they add an entry which includes their id, the client's id, and the date. Occasionally, an attendant will work with more than one client on the same day. I would like to capture when this happens. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    timesheet_lines tsl1
WHERE   EXISTS
(
SELECT  *
FROM    timesheet_lines tsl2
WHERE   tsl1.date = tsl2.date
AND tsl1.attendant_id = tsl2.attendant_id
AND tsl1.client_id <> tsl2.client_id
AND tsl1.date between '2014-04-01' AND '2014-06-30'
LIMIT 2,5
)
```

I only want to display results where an attendant worked with at least 2 different clients. I don't expect it to be possible to have more than 5 on a single day. This is why I am using LIMIT 2,5.

I am also only interested in April through June of this year.

I think I may have the right syntax, but the query seems to be taking forever to run. Is there a faster query? There should be only about 42000+ entries all together for this particular date range. I am not expecting to get more than about 500-600 results that meet the criteria.

I ended up using the following:

```
create TEMPORARY table tempTSL1
 (date1 date, start1 time, end1 time, attend1 varchar(50), client1 varchar(50), type1 tinyint);
insert into tempTSL1(date1, start1, end1, attend1, client1, type1)
select date, start_time, end_time, attendant_id, client_id, type
from timesheet_lines
WHERE
timesheet_lines.date BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-06-30'
and timesheet_lines.type IN (1,2,5,6);

create TEMPORARY table tempTSL2
 (date2 date, start2 time, end2 time, attend2 varchar(50), client2 varchar(50), type2 tinyint);
insert into tempTSL2(date2, start2, end2, attend2, client2, type2)
select date, start_time, end_time, attendant_id, client_id, type
from timesheet_lines
WHERE
timesheet_lines.date BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-06-30'
and timesheet_lines.type IN (1,2,5,6);

SELECT *
FROM tempTSL1
WHERE (attend1,date1) IN (
    SELECT attend2
        ,date2
    FROM tempTSL2 tsl2
    GROUP BY attend2
        ,date2
    HAVING COUNT(date2) > 1
)
GROUP BY attend1
    ,client1
    ,date1
HAVING COUNT(client1) = 1

ORDER BY date1,attend1,start1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely making it much more complex than it needs to be. Try something like this:

```
SELECT attendant_id
    ,client_id
    ,date
FROM timesheet_lines
WHERE (attendant_id,date) IN (
    SELECT attendant_id
        ,date
    FROM timesheet_lines tsl1
    GROUP BY attendant_id
        ,date
    HAVING COUNT(date) > 1
)
GROUP BY attendant_id
    ,client_id
    ,date
HAVING COUNT(client_id) = 1
```

The subquery returns results only of attendants performing multiple activities on the same date. The top query will pull from the same table, matching the attendant and dates of activity, and filter the result set to items where there is only 1 client in the grouping. Example:

```
attendant_id            client_id            date
1                       A                    2014-01-01
1                       B                    2014-01-01
2                       C                    2014-01-01
2                       D                    2014-01-02
```

Will return:

```
attendant_id            client_id            date
1                       A                    2014-01-01
1                       B                    2014-01-01
```

Untested, but I think it should be in line with what you are looking for, assuming the following two statements are true:

- You are not trying to capture two different attendants working the same client on the same day
- An attendant can only perform one activity per client per day

If the second point is not true, then you will need to incorporate additional fields into the subquery (such as an `activity_id` or something).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: I ended up using the following: